# How to prevent my Retina MacBook Pro from accessing Internet when sleeping?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos

When I close my Retina Macbook Pro's lid and put it to sleep, I have noticed that it periodically must "wake" and check the internet or connect to Wi-Fi when I expect it to be sleeping.  This has been consistent for me even with my previous MacBook Pro, too.

I see this because my Gmail tab in Chrome will have new emails preloaded, before the Wi-Fi connection is reenabled.  Or when I have an IRC client open, I'll see multiple join/disconnects in the log.

`pmset -g sched` does not print anything.

How can I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Try disabling Power Nap https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032

Comment: Before enable the sleep mode turn off Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: @Mattia This is, at best, a workaround. It's certainly no fix.

Comment: @enderland Could you add the output of `pmset -g sched`?

Comment: @MaxRied done. Arc that seems promising...

Comment: @enderland This means that there is no time scheduled wake up, so it certainly is an interesting information.

Comment: @enderland Does `pmset -g log | grep DarkWake` output anything, and if, do the times and dates correspond to the wakeups you experience?

Comment: @Arc676, You should create an answer with info from that link. I'd +1 it you did.

Comment: @user3439894 Unfortunately, the link doesn't say anything about applications also doing things while the Mac is in sleep mode (only mentions Mail and iCloud). I can't be certain that this is actually the root cause, and I can't test it because my Mac doesn't support Power Nap. At best I can wait for OP to test and post results.